# link in <header> not clickable

Tags: html, css, header

I've the following problem

If I put a clickable image in my header, you can't click on it. *(or common link, both don't work)*

When I try re-positioning the image, outside the `header` - it works.
But when it's still in the `header` you can't click on it.

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #454d58;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  z-index: -10;
  min-width: 100%;
}
li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
LINK
</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you a have a negative `z-index` on your `header`, change it to a positive one or remove it.

negative `z-index` gets lower in the stacked context order, so you wont be able to click on it

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #454d58;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1; /*whatever you need - want here - or just remove it */
  min-width: 100%;
}
li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
LINK
</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default all the elements of the html are set to `z-index: 0;`. 
So, the body of the HTML is also at the `z-index:0;`.

And when you are setting `z-index:-10` it is putting the header behind the body itself. and hence it is not clickable including its child elements i.e link

Change `z-index: -10;` to `z-index: 0;`

```css
header {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 80px;
background-color: #454d58;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
z-index: 0;
min-width: 100%;
}


li {
position: absolute;
top: 25px;  
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#">
LINK
</a>
</li>
</ul>        
</header> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are saying that:

```
z-index: -10;
```

Why you need `z-index` there? You are just putting the link behind the header that's why you can't click it. Try changing it to `1` or remove it.